# Информация о процессе на экране в реальном времени

Tags: jquery, ajax, php, javascript

Здравствуйте.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно сделать отображения на сайте какого-либо процесса на сервере?
Пусть для примера будет обычный цикл:

```
foreach (range(1, 100) as $number) {
    echo $number;
    sleep(1);
}
```

Возможно ли через JS (jQuery) сделать вывод этих чисел в реальном времени?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самое простое: cделайте на сервере ручку, которая будет возвращать текущий прогресс, и периодически ее дергайте со странички.

**Обновление**

Что вы понимаете под файлом? CGI скрипт? Тут сильно зависит от того, какая у вас архитектура клиент-серверного взаимодействия. Например, сихронно ли выполняется задача (с точки зрения клиента). Можно сделать так: есть скрипт, который запускает задачу. При обращении к нему задаче присваевается уникальный id, который возвращается клиенту. Задача периодически записывает в файл с именем, например, /tmp/progress_{id} текущий прогресс. Есть другой скрипт, который принимает id как параметр, и возвращает содержимое этого файла. Через этот скрипт клиент и узнает о текущем прогрессе.

Comment: То есть мы через ajax запускаем файл, в нём выполняется, допустим, цикл, который записывает данные в сессии, а каждую секунду мы обращаемся к файлу, который возвращает данные из сессии, так, что ли?

Comment: Что вы понимаете под файлом? CGI скрипт? Тут сильно зависит от того, какая у вас архитектура клиент-серверного взаимодействия. Например, сихронно ли выполняется задача (с точки зрения клиента). Можно сделать так: есть скрипт, который запускает задачу. При обращении к нему задаче присваевается уникальный id, который возвращается клиенту. Задача периодически записывает в файл с именем, например, /tmp/progress_{id} текущий прогресс. Есть другой скрипт, который принимает id как параметр, и возвращает содержимое этого файла. Через этот скрипт клиент и узнает о текущем прогрессе.